# youtube data api and node.js Error: Required parameter: part

Tags: javascript, node.js, youtube, youtube-data-api

```
var fs = require('fs');
var readline = require('readline');
var google = require('googleapis');
var googleAuth = require('google-auth-library');

// If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
// at ~/.credentials/youtube-nodejs-quickstart.json
var SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly'];
var TOKEN_DIR = (process.env.HOME || process.env.HOMEPATH ||
    process.env.USERPROFILE) + '/.credentials/';
var TOKEN_PATH = TOKEN_DIR + 'youtube-nodejs-quickstart.json';

// Load client secrets from a local file.
fs.readFile('client_secret.json', function processClientSecrets(err, content) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Error loading client secret file: ' + err);
        return;
    }
    // Authorize a client with the loaded credentials, then call the YouTube API.
    authorize(JSON.parse(content), getChannel);
});

/**
 * Create an OAuth2 client with the given credentials, and then execute the
 * given callback function.
 *
 * @param {Object} credentials The authorization client credentials.
 * @param {function} callback The callback to call with the authorized client.
 */
function authorize(credentials, callback) {
    var clientSecret = credentials.installed.client_secret;
    var clientId = credentials.installed.client_id;
    var redirectUrl = credentials.installed.redirect_uris[0];
    var auth = new googleAuth();
    var oauth2Client = new auth.OAuth2(clientId, clientSecret, redirectUrl);

    // Check if we have previously stored a token.
    fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, function (err, token) {
        if (err) {
            getNewToken(oauth2Client, callback);
        } else {
            oauth2Client.credentials = JSON.parse(token);
            callback(oauth2Client);
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Get and store new token after prompting for user authorization, and then
 * execute the given callback with the authorized OAuth2 client.
 *
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} oauth2Client The OAuth2 client to get token for.
 * @param {getEventsCallback} callback The callback to call with the authorized
 *     client.
 */
function getNewToken(oauth2Client, callback) {
    var authUrl = oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
        access_type: 'offline',
        scope: SCOPES
    });
    console.log('Authorize this app by visiting this url: ', authUrl);
    var rl = readline.createInterface({
        input: process.stdin,
        output: process.stdout
    });
    rl.question('Enter the code from that page here: ', function (code) {
        rl.close();
        oauth2Client.getToken(code, function (err, token) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('Error while trying to retrieve access token', err);
                return;
            }
            oauth2Client.credentials = token;
            storeToken(token);
            callback(oauth2Client);
        });
    });
}

/**
 * Store token to disk be used in later program executions.
 *
 * @param {Object} token The token to store to disk.
 */
function storeToken(token) {
    try {
        fs.mkdirSync(TOKEN_DIR);
    } catch (err) {
        if (err.code != 'EEXIST') {
            throw err;
        }
    }
    fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, JSON.stringify(token));
    console.log('Token stored to ' + TOKEN_PATH);
}

/**
 * Lists the names and IDs of up to 10 files.
 *
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} auth An authorized OAuth2 client.
 */
function getChannel(auth) {
    var service = google.youtube('v3');
    service.channels.list({
        auth: auth,
        part: 'snippet,contentDetails,statistics',
        forUsername: 'GoogleDevelopers'
    }, function (err, response) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
            return;
        }
        var channels = response.items;
        if (channels.length == 0) {
            console.log('No channel found.');
        } else {
            console.log('This channel\'s ID is %s. Its title is \'%s\', and ' +
                        'it has %s views.',
                        channels[0].id,
                        channels[0].snippet.title,
                        channels[0].statistics.viewCount);
        }
    });
}
```

I copied the code from youtube's data API tutorial for node.js
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/quickstart/nodejs

I entered the password from the link in the first time.

and now when I run the application I get this output:
**The API returned an error: Error: Required parameter: part**

this is part

```
part: 'snippet,contentDetails,statistics',
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this is not what you are asking for, but reverting back to version 24.0.0 worked for me:

excerpt from my packages.json

```
...
"googleapis": "24.0.0",
...
```