# Error: Required parameter: part

Tags: node.js, youtube-data-api

I am working with Youtube data API with node after following the sample steps form documentation. I ran into this Error The API returned an error.
 **Error: Required parameter: part**

Answer (score 1):

Quick-fix is to revert to googleapis version 24.0.0:

```
npm uninstall googleapis --save
npm install googleapis@24.0.0 --save
```

Found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48401302/youtube-data-api-and-node-js-error-required-parameter-part).